# SelectList with a null selection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a bunch of drop down lists in my view, such as this one:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Process, Model.ProcessList)
```

They all take in a `SelectList` based on data from a database table like this:

```
ProcessList = new SelectList(_db.Processes, "ID", "Name");
```

where `_db.Processes` returns a `ObjectSet<Process>`.

The issue I have is that sometimes the property that is set by the drop down list can be no selection, i.e. `null`.  How can I add a `null` selection to the `SelectList`>

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Process, Model.ProcessList,"--Select Process--")
```

The above line would add `--select process--` at the top of select list and if this value is selected, empty string will be posted and bound property will be set to null (Process in this case)

Comment: I have found a problem with this. When you supply the 'optionLabel' parameter the dropdown no longer selects the current item based on the SelectList `selectedValue` parameter. It always selects the default option when editing. Any suggestions?

Comment: what you are telling should only happen when the relevant property of the model does not contain any value. For example if value of `model.Process` is null or something that is not present in the list, it will select label by default.

Comment: I have found that as soon as I add a null entry to the list (via the model, or via the label option) it will only select the first item by default. I have switched to using a KendoUI DropDownList and the problem went away so I am assuming it may be a bug with the standard DropDownList (or my project configuration). KendoUI's dropdown requires a non-null value (e.g. 0) in all entries so it is not a perfect solution.

Comment: I have this same problem... nullable Boolean, when a null is the value of it instead of selecting, what in this case would be "--Select Process--", it selects the first value (2nd option) in the DDL... can I fix this without having to resort to setting 0 or -1 or something?